# My Cordova app freezes after 64 consecutive calls to findEvent

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm refreshing my App with the latest iOS(9), Xcode(7A220) and Cordova(5.3.1) versions. I'm using the Calendar plugin from Eddy Verbruggen, and it works fine if just a few calls are made at once, but...
I have one page in my app that displays a list of events - it has 77 events now. By each event, I offer a link to 'add to calendar' or 'remove from calendar', depending upon if the event is in the Calendar. After populating the primary html of the list(without those add/remove links), I go through another loop(because of the asynchronous nature of the javascript programming) to call findEvent on each and then add the appropriate link to each event listing via javascript. This has been working fine over the last few years, but when I try it now, it consistently freezes on the 64th call without an error. If I limit it to 63 calls, then it works perfectly. But once I do the 64th call, none of the success callback functions fire. It seems to be the same behavior on an iPhone 6 or the emulated iPhone. Is there some sort of call stack I could be over running? It appears to be using 42MB when it freezes, almost as if it has a limit of 42 on the real iPhone, but in emulation it uses more memory. I get no errors...

I tried to eliminate possible problems caused by the overhead of an options array by using a bare bones findEvent call in ObjC:(but I got the same behavior)

```
- (NSArray*) findEKEventsWithTitleAndDate: (NSString *)title
                       startDate: (NSDate *)startDate
                         endDate: (NSDate *)endDate {

  if (title != (id)[NSNull null] && title.length > 0) {
    title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"withString:@"\\'"];
  }

  NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title contains[c] '%@'", title];

  NSPredicate *matches;
  NSArray  *datedEvents, *matchingEvents;

  if (predicateString.length > 0) {
    matches = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

    datedEvents = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:[eventStore     predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:nil]];

    matchingEvents = [datedEvents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matches];
  } else {

    datedEvents = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:[eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:nil]];

    matchingEvents = datedEvents;
  }

  return matchingEvents;
}
```

Comment: This is a question for the plugin author. It may be a bug, or a feature as the author.

Comment: I've tried to take most of that out of the equation by trimming down the ObjectiveC call to the bare bones. I'll include the code above...

Comment: I guess I was not clear. If you are having this problem, you need to speak to the author. If you are having a problem with the code, this is the wrong forum.